# Найти все ссылки в тексте

Tags: веб-программирование, php

Здравствуйте! Как сделать так, чтобы в тексте найти все ссылки типа `http://www.hashcode.ru` или `www.hashcode.ru` и поместить их в массив?

Answer (score 4):

Ваш текст в формате HTML? Вам не обойтись без парсера. Например, [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm):

```
$html = file_get_html('http://your.site.here');
$result = array();
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
    $result[] = $element->href;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$html=file_get_contains('http://www.hashcode.ru')
preg_match_all('/<a[^>(href=)]+href="http:\/\/(www\.)?hashcode.ru"[^>]+>([A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9 ]+)<\/a>/isu', $html, $array);
print_r($array);
```

в массиве все тексты, что находятся между тегами <a></a> с href как в поставленной задаче.

Comment: Угу, а если не так выглядит тег?

Comment: например как?

Comment: @Arc, `<a href="http://www.hashcode.ru" style="red">HashCode</a>`

Comment: исправил, теперь нормец.

Comment: @Arc а если тэг выглядит так: 

    <a style="red" href="http://www.hashcode.ru">Hashcode</a> ? :)

Comment: Да вам что, делать всем что ли нечего? ;) Исправил.

Answer (score 1):

Для поиска ссылок(URL) в тексте или на HTML страницах попробуйте библиотеку [url-finder](https://github.com/mxkh/url-finder). Ее можно установить при помощи composer `composer require mxkh/url-finder`

Так же есть поддержка поиска видео ссылок популярных сервисов, таких как Youtube, Vimeo, RuTube.

Надеюсь это поможет кому-то.